# Discord.py nickname changin

Tags: python, discord.py

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def ani(ctx, member: discord.Member, nick):
    if member == discord.Member:
        member = ctx.message.author
        await member.edit(nick=nick)
    else:
        member = ctx.message.author
        await member.edit(nick=nick)
```

I have read multiple tutorials and the documentation. I do not understand why my code does not work as expected.

Please help, thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @Makashi. If the given answer helps you, please mark it as the accepted answer. If there are still some errors or unexpected behaviour you are seeing, please provide more details as part of your question (this is generally expected).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code, or things that could be done better. I will list them out here.

- **Originally define your variables as `None`**: If a member isn't mentioned, your bot will throw an error telling you that you missed a variable. The same can be said if you don't include a nickname for `nick`. To combat this, you can make `None` the default variable by using `=None` after each of your variables (excluding `ctx`, of course). You can handle them later on.
- **Change `if member == discord.Member` to just `if member`**: Since you already have member defined as a `discord.Member` object, this statement would not work. If you previously defined your variables as `None`, then you can simply use `if member` to check if this variable is *not* `None`. If it is, it will immediately go to the `else` statement.
- **Catch other errors with a `try-except` statement**: To avoid errors from flooding in your console, you can instead tell the `ctx.author` what went wrong. Using `try` and `except`, you can catch errors such as `Missing Permissions` or `Invalid Form Body`.
- **Use * before nick**: If you do not use an asterisk before your nick variable, you will find that the following will happen:

[image: What will happen without the *]

Here is the above expressed in the code below.

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def ani(ctx, member: discord.Member=None, *, nick=None):
    if nick == None:
        nick = "A Cool Nickname"
    try:
        if member:
            name_before = member.display_name 
            # Why not member.nick? If the member did not have a nickname to begin with,
            # member.nick would return None
            await member.edit(nick=nick)
        else:
            member = ctx.message.author
            name_before = member.display_name 
            await member.edit(nick=nick)
        await ctx.send(f"Changed {member.mention}'s nickname from {name_before} to {member.display_name}")
    except Exception as e:
        # 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions 
            # - You are above the bot in the role hierarchy
            # - The bot does not have the ability to change nicknames
        # 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
            # - In nick: Must be 32 or fewer in length.
        await ctx.send(str(e))
```

[image: above code working]

---

If you want to make it a bit more complex, you could include a [`typing.Optional`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#typing-optional) (`import typing`), which would allow the `ctx.author` to change their own nickname without having to mention themselves (and avoiding nasty errors). All you have to do is replace a single line.

```py
async def ani(ctx, member: typing.Optional[discord.Member]=None, *, nick=None):
```

[image: Works the same way as before, but better]

Comment: Ahh, thanks, I didn't see your comment until now, my code is working now.